# Where can I find a (current) example of code to bulk upload data to Google AppEngine? (For localhost, too.)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've tried to do it like they describe in the [AppEngine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data) but I can't get it to accept my upload. (I haven't tried to download.) I want to get it working in the development environment before I tried on the live site.

It's kind of confusing, because I don't know if I should be trying appcfg.py or bulkloader.py. (I mostly tried appcfg.py.) I think it's an authentication problem, as it keeps asking me for the email/password. (Even after I removed 'login: admin' from app.yaml.)

I did --dry_run and it seemed to work, so I think my stuff is well formed.

Before asking for specific debugging help, I thought I would ask if anyone knows of working sample code that I can download. I run OS X 10.6, if anyone cares. I'm not new to Python, and have a lot of web.py experience, so it's probably not unfamiliarity with the language that's tripping me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs have [a section](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) on uploading and downloading data, with examples. You should be using appcfg.py unless you need one of the features of bulkloader.py that are not yet integrated, such as --dump/--restore functionality.

It sounds like the authentication problems you're having are related to Google Apps: If you have an App Engine app that allows any Google account to authenticate, and you have a Google Apps account as administrator, you won't be able to authenticate against your app as an administrator with it, even if you have created a Google account for that email address. You need to create a gmail account, and add that account as an administrator, so you can use that address when you need to authenticate against your app.

Comment: I was hoping there was a downloadable example out there, those were the docs I was reading. The gmail account that owns my appengine apps is just my plain gmail account, it wasn't created with Google Apps... I would have thought that would be the administrator? How do you manage administrators for an AppEngine app?